# Two lists of DateTimes - searching for chains of "bumps"

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an app, that is connecting two clients together. Now, after client connects, he starts sending "bumps" - when a bump hits the server, the time is being added to a `List<DateTime>`. Now, since there are two clients connected together - there are two lists.

What I want to do, is that I want to look through both lists, and find timespans when both users were sending bumps with time difference of 60 seconds.

Example:

```
Bumps of user1:
18:28:00
18:28:30
18:29:30
18:30:00
18:30:30

Bumps of user2:
18:29:00
18:30:00
```

Since `user2` has sent only two bumps, and `user1` was also sending bumps in the same time (60sec difference), the timespan of both users should be 1 minute.

Is there any algorithm that can compute that?

Edit for clarification: I want to get as short timespan as possible, also there might be a big gap of nothing, ant then there might be another timespan (so basically there will be many timespans).

Comment: You could probably use a modified merge sort algorithm.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete explanation for how to calculate the timespan? Why isn't 2.5 minutes (18:28:00 - 18:30:30) the right answer? I think so because user2 was online within 60 seconds of those times.

Comment: @Dukeling: We are counting the shortest timespan possible. Therefore, when `user2` starts adding his bumps, the whole thing starts.

Comment: Are the bumps going to be contiguous, making only one set for a session?  (e.g., no big jump for user1, where the next value is 18:40:00)  In that case, all you need is Min(user1.endTime, user2.endTime) - Max(user1.startTime, user2.startTime).  That's the first to leave minus the last to enter.  If the bumps aren't contiguous, then you would need to split them into timespans, and do the same kind of calculation.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: They are not going to be contiguous, there will be many of those sessions, that's my bad, I didn't write that, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very similar to merge step in merge sort.

If X and Y are the list of bump times, sort them first. After that keep moving through both of these lists with the following condition:

```
If diff(X[i],Y[j]) < 60 "Output something";

If (X[i]<Y[j])i++;
Else j++;
```